# AVFoundation get album image of song

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I want to get album image/cover of song. Is it possible? I'm using AVPlayer for audio streaming, and i need to get album cover, if song contains it. Like in iTunes.

**SOLUTION:**

```
UIImage *img = nil;
NSArray *metadata = _avplayer.currentItem.asset.commonMetadata;
for(AVMetadataItem *item in metadata){
    if([item.commonKey isEqualToString:@"artwork"]){
       NSData *data = item.value[@"data"];
       img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
       return img;
    }
}
return img;
```

Comment: Hello, Have u found out how to get album cover? I tried to user last fm service but singer in my radio are not popular , so I could not get album cover ((

Answer (score 1):

You should try this, but I use MPMusicPlayer:

```
musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
currentItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];
if (currentItem == nil) {
    //Not playing
}
else 
{
    NSString *name = [currentItem valueForProperty:@"title"];
    int length = [name length];
    if (length > 30) {
        name = [name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 30)];
        name = [name stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
    }
    NSString *album = [currentItem valueForProperty:@"albumTitle"];
    int lengthAl = [album length];
    if (lengthAl > 30) {
        album = [album substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 30)];
        album = [album stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
    }
    NSString *artist = [currentItem valueForProperty:@"artist"];
    int lengthAr = [artist length];
    if (lengthAr > 30) {
        artist = [artist substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 30)];
        artist = [artist stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
    }
    MPMediaItemArtwork *artworkPrev = [currentItem valueForProperty:@"artwork"];
    if (artworkPrev != nil)
    {
        UIImage *img = [artworkPrev imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(65, 65)];
        UIImageView *imgNew = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
        imgNew.frame = CGRectMake(-15,-20, 65, 65);
    }
}
```

As you can see I use a NSMakeRange, I use it only to not leave the space in my application. I hope that helps you

Comment: This is for local playing only. I need to get image while streaming:) But thanks, this will be useful someday

Comment: Also need album cover from streaming music!

Answer (score 0):

Provided your files are the right format, i.e. MP3, you can load the file's data into an ID3 tag parser. [Here's an example of one.](https://github.com/notjosh/Id3ArtViewer) It's made for OS X, but it looks like it should port to iOS fairly easily.